# Hide selected columns in datagrid vb6

Tags: datagrid, vb6, hide

I have a datagrid object and the users requested to be able to select any columns and hide them.
I guess I have to loop through the columns and check if they are selected(?) but I can't find a way to do this.
Could someone give me a tip in this?
I feel like creating excel in vb6, so if it's possible to make excel to use oracle datatable as it's source, I'm up for that too :)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataGrid has a HeadClick event you could easily use for this.  It provides the `colindex` of the clicked column.

You could combine this with a CheckBox having its `Style = vbButtonGraphical` to make a "hide clicked columns" push-on-push-off button or something if you want a clicked column heading to have multiple meanings.